# ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: syntax

B_ AUTOD_T = Beta('B_ ivtt1', 0, None, None, 0)

I have this error, any recommendation, please.

File "", line 6
B_ AUTOD_T = Beta('B_ ivtt1', 0, None, None, 0)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: What programming language, environment, etc. is this? Did you try a web search of the problem first?

Comment: Biogem, I couldn't paste the whole code. Yes I did a search no success